# Google remarketing tag on Wordpress site: can't find the CDATA comment

Tags: google, wordpress, google-tag-manager, remarketing

I have been struggling fixing the CDATA comment problem every time I inserted Google remarketing tag on our Wordpress e-commerce site. I

Google tag assistant says it can't find the CDATA comment. For further info, I inserted the remarketing tag in the *header.php* after the `<body>` tag.